# Class that extends itself. Symfony docs

Tags: php, symfony, oop

Few mounts ago I decided to learn PHP and Symfony framework,so I'm quite new in this language and instrument. I know all basic principles of OOP-principles, PHP syntax and another different interesting stuff. When I started to read Symfony docs, about Profiler->Data Collectors, here is the URL: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html.
After a few minutes of reading, I meet code like this :

```
// src/Kernel.php
class Kernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(CustomInterface::class)
            ->addTag('app.custom_tag')
        ;
    }
}
```

As I know inheritance prohibit extending like this. So when I trying to wrote this code in PhpStorm, he gives out next error: "Class should extend dby itself".
How can one class extend by himself? And why do I need this opportunity?Or it's just mistake in docs?

Comment: Seems like a error in the docs, in the code itself the kernel extends baseKernel (`class Kernel extends BaseKernel`), since as you mentioned it is not possible to exted itself

Comment: This was second about what I thought about, you confirmed my conjecture. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,that just mistake, maybe he want to write like this

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    //....
}
```